# Test Case in Selenium is not working for a Java Script Pop Up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I installed the selenium plugin in Firefox for automating a monitoring process. When i record the test case and rerun it it fails for pop up validation in the end. So i'm i'm confirming the monitoring as successful when i got a pop up at the end saying "successful". So i record the test case using selenium and when i rerun it at the end when its waiting for pop up to come two things are happening

1. the pop up in the record playback its not coming up.
2. the test case is failing for the pop up.

Please also suggest if i can use IE with selenium

Comment: Selenium IDE supports only Firefox. For more automation and browser use please user selenium web driver. Also your question is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the update. yes i'm using the Selenium web driver only now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You can check very good and easy example for how to handle javascript popup using selenum web driver : [Selenium Webdriver for Javascript popup](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-confirmation-prompts)

To use IE with selenium web driver do following :

1 - Download IE driver of selenium web driver from [HERE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

2 - You can all IE driver from selenium web driver as per below :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:/IEDriver.exe");

InternetExplorerDriver IEDriver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Note : In above code **"D:/IEDriver.exe"** is example path , you please set actual path where you have put your IE drivers.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly...  :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)